# If $D= \{ (g,g) |g\in G\} \subseteq G \times G$ is normal subgroup, then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, and we define $D= \{ (g,g) |g\in G\} \subseteq G \times G$. Show that if D is a normal subgroup of $G \times G$ then $G$ is abelian.

I showed the other way around, but I can't get this direction.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** $(hgh^{-1},g)=(h,1)(g,g)(h,1)^{-1}\in D$.